# Method of migration of MySQL version to a new server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, centos, migration

For some technical reasons, I have to migrate our actual server, running on CentOS, to a new server, but running on Ubuntu.

I MUST keep the SQL DB as it is now, same version of MySQL, etc.
I have tried several dump scripts and methods, but impossible to import the dumps to a newer version of MySQL.

So I'm thinking of copying the */var/lib/MySQL* folder and other MySQL folders to the new server.
What's your opinion about this ? Will it work ?

I was also thinking of going to the recovery console of the old server and doing an `rsync` to the new server, this way I copy the entire system to the new server.
But that's a bit heavy in my opinion. and I don't know Unix enough to `remount` discs and perform all tasks that would make the copy work.

Comment: Did you try to use MySQL Workbench? Its tools seem to work quite well exporting and importing.

Comment: Isn't there a contradiction in "I MUST keep the SQL DB as it is now, **same version of MySQL, etc**.... I have tried several dump scripts and methods, but impossible to import the dumps to **a newer version of MySQL.**"  It's not clear for me whether you want to migrate only the data or also the MySQL database server and utilities code (or at least ensure you have the same MySQL server version also on the new server)?

Comment: There are many methods. Easiest one will be taking SQL dump of your database using export option and install on other machine from the import option.But it's not a safe method for the 
large database.

Comment: Pablo : Yes I did and it didn't work.
@fvu   I would like to migrate only the sql dumps, but I have tried many many methods without success... This is a huge DB of 55Gb.
So I think it comes from the MySQL version of the new server.
Therefore my goal now is to migrate the data, but also the MySQL server and utilities.

Comment: It should work (you're not the first who needs to migrate a database :) ) so it might be wise first to focus on what went wrong and why before trying to migrate the database binaries, which **is** a **very bad** idea.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, but unfortunately I'm not skilled enough to find what the issue is...
In the DB there is some text fields with very long texts, HTML code inside, polish, czech and german caracters wrongly encoded in utf8.... a big mess :)
At least by migrating binaries I'll have the same basis for work

Comment: You haven't given ***any indication*** wrt what is not working.  Now, if you want to transplant the binaries, have fun, but be aware that you'll basically end up with a broken server that's not properly patchable anymore, or that may break when you apply other seemingly unrelated updates or patches.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually several ways to do this. The first and by far the best is what the commenters have said. Use `mysqldump` to create a sql file then import it onto the other machine. If space is an issue on one of the machines you can import more directly like so: `mysqldump {YOUR OPTIONS HERE} | mysql -h {NEWSERVER} -u root -p`

You should do the above method if at all possible. It will work better 100% of the time when doing cross version imports. Just fix the errors you see. You may need to rewrite triggers and stored procedures if the syntax differs across versions.

If you know the danger and are ok with losing your data, you can try the following xtrabackup method:

1. Install xtrabackup on the older server (http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup)
2. Get a full and consistent backup from xtrabackup (read the docs)
3. Shutdown mysql on the new server
4. Copy the backup from xtrabackup to that new server
5. Start up mysql again, it may take a while as it upgrades the tables

**I have done this before across mysql server versions, BUT this is not reliable, and you quite possibly could end up with unreliable or corrupted data. Do it at your own risk.**